# Second monitor detected but doesn't turn on

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors, connected via HDMI, DVI-I and DVI-D. This last one is correctly detected inside the OS but doesn't turn on. I have a AMD R9 380X with the latest drivers installed. I've tried different distros, all of them have this problem, lots of stuff I found online like deleting monitor settings, forcing configurations with `xrandr`, nothing works. In Windows, everything works normally.

`xrandr` output:

[image: xrandr]

Display settings:

[image: Display settings]

AMD driver:

[image: AMD driver]

Is there a way fix to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by plugging the monitor to another port. Was using a DVI-D (with an adaptor to VGA) and I bought a Display Port to VGA adaptor and now it's working. I'm gonna light a candle to everyone that has this problem and doesn't have a extra port.